# CNN to classify images from a small dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am trying to build a model that can classify a set of images. I think my main problem is that I have few images in the test set: 100 images.  For the training phase I kept a percentage of 80% for training (310 images) and 20% for validation (78 images) and kept the same percentage between the training + validation images (80%, 388 images) and the test images (20%, 100 images).

As I mentioned, my goal is to build a classifier that can classify the test images into one of 6 outputs. For that reason, I divided the images in the Training and Validation folders into 6 subfolders named according to the categories of interest (e.g., deforestation, glaciers), and I divided the images in the testing folder into 6 subfolders that are named differently: A, B, C, D, E, F.

I tried changing the parameters of the epochs several times but when I test the accuracy of the model I get a very low value, the highest value I got was 20%. How can I improve that?

Here is the code:

```py
!pip install keras
!pip install tensorflow

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

#importing Libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import random

#import Library for data Visualization
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import cv2

#transporting Tensorflow for modeal creation and its dependencies
import tensorflow

#Generate batches of tensor image data with real-time data augmentation
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

#for enabling inline plotting
# %matplotlib inline

TrainingImagePath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Training'
TestingImagePath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Test'
ValidationImagePath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Validation'

# Defining the pre-processing transformation on raw images of training data
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.1,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

# Defining pre-processing transformations on raw images of testing data
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Generating the Training Data
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TrainingImagePath,
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

# Generating the Testing Data
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TestingImagePath,
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

# Generating the Validation Data
valid_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    ValidationImagePath,
    target_size=(128, 128),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)


def showImages(class_name):
    folder_path = os.path.join(TrainingImagePath, class_name)
    images_list = os.listdir(folder_path)

    random_index = random.choice(images_list)
    image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, random_index)

    plt.imshow(mpimg.imread(image_path))
    plt.title(class_name)
    plt.axis(False)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for labels, number in training_set.class_indices.items():
    plt.subplot(6, 6, number+1)
    showImages(labels)

TrainClasses=training_set.class_indices

ResultMap={}
for ballvalue, ballName in zip(TrainClasses.values(), TrainClasses.keys()):
  ResultMap[ballvalue]=ballName

import pickle
with open(R"/content/drive/MyDrive/Results.pk1", "wb") as f:
  pickle.dump(ResultMap, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

print("Mapping of Face and its ID", ResultMap)

OutputNeurons=len(ResultMap)
print('\n The number of output neurons:', OutputNeurons)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPool2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

classifier=Sequential()

classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), input_shape=(128,128,3), activation="relu"))

classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1),activation="relu"))

classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(OutputNeurons, activation="softmax"))

classifier.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"])

classifier.summary()

import time

# Measuring the time taken by the model to train
StartTime = time.time()

# Starting the model training
model_history = classifier.fit_generator(
    training_set,
    steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=valid_set,
    validation_steps=len(valid_set),
    verbose=1
)

EndTime = time.time()
print('############# Total Time Taken: {:.2f} Minutes ###############'.format(total_time_minutes))

accuracy=model_history.history['accuracy']
val_accuracy=model_history.history['val_accuracy']

loss=model_history.history['loss']
val_loss=model_history.history['val_loss']

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(accuracy,label="Training accuracy")
plt.plot(val_accuracy, label="Validation accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.title ("Training vs validation accuracy")

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(loss, label="Training loss")
plt.plot(val_loss, label="Validation loss")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Training vs validation loss")

plt.show()

classifier.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/Classifier.pk1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

First: I'd recommend you to remove all code that is not really part of your question (-> visualization)

Second: Your training steps ignore the batch size. For each step, 32 images are processed. So you want to set the steps to `images // batch size`

Third: As you said, your subdirectories are named differently. Your model should always(?) outperform a random benchmark (so accuracy should roughly exceed 1/6 in your case). If that isn't your case, you have probably messed up your labels:

Since the labels are one-hot encoded with respect the the subdirectories (I guess in alphabetical order), you will have different encodings for the same class in your case. You can either rename your subdirectories to match each other or provide a list of classes as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64984765/9659620) (pass ["dogs", "cats"] to training source and ["B", "A"] to test source if A=cats and B=dogs.